# Selenium how to select last link in a body?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a html page like below

```
<body>
    
    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="a.php">A</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="b.php">B</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="c.php">C</a>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="d.php">D</a>
    </div>
        
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="f.php">F</a>

</body>
```

I need to select last link `F`. I have tried like below

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[last()]")
```

It's selecting `D`

I also tried below way

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/body//a[last()]")
```

In this time unable to locate element. How can I get last link here in an easy way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the **last** element. Try following `xpath`.

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a)[last()]")
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `driver.findElements()` method and put the return value in an array.

The last link will be the last element of the array.

I suggest you to (for various reasons):

1. do `yourArray = driver.findElements(By.tag("a"))`
2. for every element check if the href attribute is not null with `element.getAttribute("href") != null` and update a myIndex var if it's not
3. The element at the index "myIndex" of "yourArray" will be the element you're searching for.

Comment: Is it not possible using last() method ?

Comment: I suggest you to make checks for attributes, an <a> WebElement could not be a link in the way you intend to elaborate it. I prefer to write long, and maybe less efficient, but reliable and safe codes.